# How to properly close a socket opened with fdopen?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, posix, glibc

I have a socket `sock`:

```
int sock = socket(...);
connect(sock, ...);
 // or sock = accept(sock_listen, 0, 0);
```

And I opened it with fdopen twice, so that I can use the buffered reader and writer in `stdio`, such as `fwrite`, `fread`, `fgets` and `fprintf`.

```
FILE *f_recv = fdopen(sock, "wb");
FILE *f_send = fdopen(sock, "rb");

// some IO here.

close(sock);
fclose(f_recv);
fclose(f_send);
```

But as we know, if I `fclose` a file, a `close` will be called subsequently, and `fclose` will fail.

And if I use only `close`, the memory of struct `FILE` is leaked.

How do I close it properly?

---

UPDATE:

Use `fdopen` once with `"r+"` makes reading and writing share the same lock, but I except the sending and receiving to work individually.

Comment: You didn't 'open it twice'. You just wrapped STDIO streams around it. You need to close them both for the reason you have given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think calling `fdopen()` twice is a mistake for the reasons you give.

Just open it once with `fdopen()`, passing the mode string `"r+b"` to make it read/write and binary.

Comment: Wait a minute ... This introduces a new problem. The `stdio` stuffs locks the "FILE" on each call, or when manually locked with `flockfile`. But actually, reading and writing should be locked individually.

Answer (score 8):

Use dup() to obtain a duplicate file descriptor for passing to fdopen(). When you call fclose() that will be closed but the underlying socket will remain open and can be closed with close():

```
FILE *f_recv = fdopen(dup(sock), "wb");
FILE *f_send = fdopen(dup(sock), "rb");

// some IO here.

fclose(f_recv);
fclose(f_send);
close(sock);
```

Edit: You can of course combine this with just using a single FILE object for both reading and writing.